# How to reveal/hide characters in PasswordBox?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-phone-8, uwp-xaml

I need to create a checkbox that will reveal password characters in two PasswordBox controls (Password and Confirm Password respectively). So, when this checkbox is checked PasswordBox must show password instead of "*********". Actually, I'm asking about property (if it exists) that controls this behavior of PasswordBox. I didn't find it on MSDN (or didn't understand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use TextBox to show characters.
You can put them over your PasswordBoxes and bind Text to Password and Visibility to IsChecked of CheckBox

Answer (score 2):

For Windows Phone 8.1 (not 8.0) there is the property [**IsPasswordRevealButtonEnabled**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.passwordbox.ispasswordrevealbuttonenabled).

Definition:

> Gets or sets a value that specifies whether the visual UI of the PasswordBox includes a button element that toggles showing or hiding the typed characters.

**XAML:**

```
<PasswordBox IsPasswordRevealButtonEnabled="bool" />
```

**C#:**

```
public bool IsPasswordRevealButtonEnabled { get; set; }
```

Comment: Sadly, I need to do this for Windows Phone 8.0.

Comment: Then I guess you'll have to use a workaround with a regular TextBox.